# Как вставить текст из excel в richTextBox C# без форматирования

Tags: c#, excel, richtextbox

Скажите, плиз, как вставить текст из excel в richTextBox C# без форматирования? Текст вставляется вместе с таблицей, а нужно вставить без таблицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно перехватить обработчик вставки, и написать свой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь о `WinForms`, то вот так:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)  
    { 
        int selectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;

        string initialText = richTextBox1.Text;
        string tail = initialText.Substring(selectionStart);

        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(initialText.Length);
        newText.Append(initialText.Substring(0, selectionStart));
        newText.Append((string) Clipboard.GetData("Text"));
        newText.Append(tail);
        richTextBox1.Text = newText.ToString();

        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength - tail.Length;

        e.Handled = true;
    } 
}
```